# How to resolve map is not a function in react

Tags: reactjs, oop

i got an err saying that 'this.state.products.map is not a function

```
 class product_list extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {products: []};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost/scandiweb-test/src/backend/list.php')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ products: response.data});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    usersList(){
        return this.state.products.map(function(object, i){
            return <RecordList obj={object} key={i}/>;
        });
    }
```

the object that i want to get is like this  `0: Object {d_sku:" Sheesh!",d_name:"Thomas Jeferson shoes,d_price:"42069"}`

Comment: are you sure response.products is an array? if it's null or undefined (or anything other than an array), you will get this error.

Comment: it's not ..i think . this is the php file  

```require 'connect.php';
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$products = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

if($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    $cr = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $products[$cr]['d_sku'] = $row['d_sku'];
    $products[$cr]['d_name'] = $row['d_name'];
    $products[$cr]['d_price'] = $row['d_price'];
    $products[$cr]['d_attribute'] = $row['d_attribute'];
    $cr++;

}

//print_r ($products);

echo json_encode($products);
}
else
{
    http_response_code(404);
}
```

Comment: oh ..i've found the solution...

axios.get('http://localhost/scandiweb-test/src/backend/list.php') the link of the axios
is like this:

Connected successfully[{"d_sku":"Shees","d_name":"Thomas Jeferson Shoes","d_price":"42069"]

it's beacause it was a string or text on the php file so it must display like this :

[{"d_sku":"Shees","d_name":"Thomas Jeferson Shoes","d_price":"42069"}] 

without the 'Connected successfully' text